# Weird behaviour on Swift protocol methods

Tags: swift, protocols

Just stumbled across a weird behavior in swift when using a protocol with optional methods which have the same name and argument types but differently named parameters.

Everything works fine if I implement none or both of the methods in my class, but as soon as I comment one out, swift complains:

> "Method 'myProtocol(foo:)' has different argument names from those
>   required by protocol 'MyProtocol' ('myProtocol(bar:)')"

The behaviour that I would expect is that I can implement an arbitrary combination (only one of the two, both or none) of the protocol methods since both methods are defined as optional.

Here's a playground file to demonstrate the issue, when you un-comment the comments or don't implement any of the protocol methods everything compiles fine.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    optional func myProtocol(foo aString: String!)
    optional func myProtocol(bar aString: String!)
}

class Test : MyProtocol {
    init() {

    }

    func myProtocol(foo aString: String!) {
        puts("myProtocol(foo aString: String!): \(aString)")
    }

    // UN-COMMENT THIS AND EVERYTHING COMPILES FINE
    /* 
    func myProtocol(bar aString: String!) {
        puts("myProtocol(bar aString: String!): \(aString)")
    }
    */
}

let foobar = Test()

foobar.myProtocol(foo: "Hello")
//foobar.myProtocol(bar: "Bye")
```

Can somebody enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know from Swift documentation for functions, `foo` and `bar` are external names for `aString` parameter. So technically he have exactly the same function with just different names of parameters that is completely legal in Objective-C:

```
id<MyProtocol> myVar;
[myVar myProtocolWithBar:@""];
[myVar myProtocolWithFoo:@""];
```

I think it is a bug in Swift compiler! File a report: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: if I implement both protocol methods in my class, everything works fine - the problem occurs with the `optional`: if I only implement one of the two protocol methods, which in theory, should be legal since they are optional. I think I'll file a report, thanks for the link!